# How to multi select the items in table without using action class for IE browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

IE browser does not support Action class. Is it possible to multi select the items in a table using any other way? If any, please share.

Please find the sample structure of the table to select the values. Now i want to select the Text1, Text3 & Text5 values. Am able to select using Action class in Chrome, FF browser using selenium 2.52.0 but not able to select in IE/Safari.

```
<table>
<tr><td><div><span>Text1<span/><div/><td/><tr/>
<tr><td><div><span>Text2<span/><div/><td/><tr/>
<tr><td><div><span>Text3<span/><div/><td/><tr/>
<tr><td><div><span>Text4<span/><div/><td/><tr/>
<tr><td><div><span>Text5<span/><div/><td/><tr/>
<table>
```

Function used to click:

```
String[] items = itemName.split("\n");// Items to be clicked
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
for(int counter = 0; counter < items.length; counter++) 
{
    this.listingRows = this.listing.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[id='mainTable']"));
    List<WebElement> element = listingRows.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class='sample']>td>div>span")); //Getting the row elements
    int itemCnt =  element.size();
    String item;
    for(int i =0;i<itemCnt;i++){
    item = element.get(i).getText();            
    if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(items[counter])){
    builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element.get(i)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
    builder.build().perform();
     }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: What are "the items"... you need to be much more specific.

Comment: @JeffC please find the updated question.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can inspect the table

```
WebElement data1=d.findElement(By.xpath(""));
```

then, select row by row

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = data1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

using loop you can repeat through out the columns

```
for (int i=0; i<rowSize; i++) 
    {
        WebElement webRow = tableRows.get(i);
        //Get all cell values in each row
        List<WebElement> allCells = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        //System.out.println(allCells.size());
        if(allCells.size() > 1)
        {
            row = st1.createRow(i);
            for (int j=0; j<allCells.size(); j++)
            {
                WebElement webCell = allCells.get(j);
                String text = webCell.getText();
                if(text.length()>3)
                {
                    cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue(webCell.getText());
                }
            }
        }
```

try once..!!

Comment: I wanted to click the multiple elements not getting the elements. Please see the updated question